# Format incoming emails in Outlook with C# add-in

Tags: c#, formatting, outlook-addin

I have a lot of emails from Taskzilla in Outlook 2012 which have very bad content formatting. I want to write an add-in in C# for Outlook 2010 which will:

1. Check if email is from taskzilla@sender.com
2. Take its body
3. Delete unnessary spaces, make some text bold (massage structure is
   always the same)
4. Show me formatted message

I am new in add-ins development. What could you suggest to read for beginning? Many thanks :)

*P.S. May be it is possible to manage without development with existing add-in?*

Answer (score 0):

You can read [VSTO book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321533216) first to learn OOM (Outlook Object Model) and conception of "form regions" to change UI